# How to put string variable at mysql_resutl field?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to run this code :

```
if ($_GET['CHOOSE'] == 1)
  { 
   $field = " 'col1' ";
  }
  else
  {
     $field = " 'col2 '  ";
  }

  echo mysql_result($result,0,$field);
```

unfortunately I got false ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if ($_GET['CHOOSE'] == 1)
{ 
 $field = "col1";
}
else
{
 $field = "col2";
}
echo mysql_result($result,0,$field);
```